How does the summoned monster know who is my enemy?
It was said that the summoned monsters would have a default behavior of attacking the caster's opponents if they have not received any command from the caster.
I am wondering how would the summoned monsters identify the opponents when they jump into the battlefield. Would they be confused if they have not been given command and just see a group of humans are fighting each other around them? Or would they automatically (and magically) learn who are their opponents and who are their allies?

your P.S. is a separate question and should have its own entry. Only one question per post, please. The stack doesn't mind dozens of valid questions from a single poster in rapid succession, though some users may be mistaken about that policy.

Well, whenever you notice something like that, a wizard did it.

@MindwinRememberMonica It was not a question, just trying to add some additional information there. Let me know if you think it should be removed.

stack exchange questions should strive to be laser-focused. If you think you can elaborate that PS into its own question, then by all means go for it. Most of the denizens who lurk in these pages, and even some moderators, often forget (or never bothered to learn) the mission of this website network.

apply the principle of charity and remember that a criticism on the content means no criticism of the author, even though we often get emotional about it. You don't need to get defensive. We are working to build a good Q&A for those who with similar Qs will search for such As.

It somehow automagically knows without being told.
From the spell description of summon monster I:

It appears where you designate and acts immediately, on your turn. It attacks your opponents to the best of its ability. If you can communicate with the creature, you can direct it not to attack, or to attack particular enemies, or to perform other actions.

It's not explicitly stated, but the creature automatically knows who your opponents are when you cast the spell, without any communication on your part. It's just an effect as part of the spell.
The only things that are certain are what it doesn't do:

It doesn't rely on your communication to know who your enemy is. Communication lets you give specific orders (e.g. attack specific enemies, or stop attacking), but by default, it knows who your enemies are even before you communicate with it.
It knows with certainty, and doesn't have to guess. A "called" creature might attack its summoner, but the spell description of summon monster is clear that it always attacks the summoner's enemies, not the summoner or their allies. The spell description leaves no potential for friendly fire.


This would likely be the most convenient way to handle that. Guess I would add that to my house rules as clarification.

:) "automagically" - what a fantastic and apt term!

What a wonderful interrogation technique. "How do we know we can trust this guy?" "Make him summon a monster he can't communicate with. If it attacks us, we can't trust him."

Point of order: The spell description says it attacks the summoner's opponents, not their enemies. Opponents are those who are opposed to the summoner; an enemy who isn't currently opposing the summoner isn't an opponent, whereas a friend who's currently playing a really intense checkers game against them is.

"It attacks your opponents to the best of its ability." What makes you sure that "the best of its ability" doesn't include its ability to distinguish who your opponents are?

In a lot of cases, it’s pretty clear pretty quickly, just by how everyone is facing one another, and something like pointing or whatever is going to be clear to most things you can summon. You could argue that some delay is justified, being dropped into the middle of melee, but if that were the way to they wanted to do it, they’d just have had the summon roll initiative. At the end of the day, they decided that some delay, some times, wasn’t worth the extra complexity, so the game left it out. As the spell description indicates, they just kind of smoothed it over and said “most of the time is now all of the time: you can point out targets well enough, quickly enough, for the summon to act as soon as they get there.”
That said, it is generally recommended for summoners to learn the languages of the things they summon. Anything more complicated than pointing at a target for “get them” is going to be quite painful otherwise.

I assume that any summoned creature would know what summoned it, and anything attacking the summoner would automatically be considered an enemy.

@Flywheel25a The issue is that most there would probably be no one attacking the summoner at the point a creature is summoned. Those wizards tend to be hiding behind something (their fighter, a wall, etc.) when they are doing so and likely are not attacked. Most likely, the creature would only see a bunch of frontier characters and summoned creatures are hitting each other while the summoner is standing outside of the mess.

@TerryWindwalker The fact that the summoner isn't being attacked by the fighter would imply that they're allies, and the fact that the fighter is facing off against a horde of monsters-of-the-week could imply that those monsters are the summoner and fighter's mutual enemies. Granted, the fact that a summoned monster has only a handful of seconds to take in the battlefield and work out what's going on makes this less plausible, but spot checks are a free action, so...

@TerryWindwalker You are thinking far, far too statically. Remember that turns are only an abstraction: everyone is actually moving the entire time, and initiative only indicates who has the “edge” on everyone else. The summon appears with the summoner, their guardian, and their enemies all in motion—and unless someone’s deliberately trying to fake out the summon, it’s usually going to be exceedingly obvious who is on which side.
